# Simple "scroll to/down" effect using minimal markup and hash tags

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto, hashtag

I am making a one page site that has a classic navigation at the top. Right now I have links set up as hash tags in order to navigate within the page:

```
<nav>
<a href="#about">About</a>
</nav>
...
<section id="about">...</section>
```

Obviously, this works but the jump to the about section is instant and not gradual. I am looking for an extremely simple implementation in order to make a gradual transition. I don't want anything fancy. No axis, offset, or any other options. I just want the scroll transition to be gradual. The only setting I want is the time it takes to finish the scroll. Also, I want to make almost no changes to my markup. I have seen several javascript plugins that require you to use anchor tags to set the locations in the html document— i don't want that. [This site](http://www.fluidbyte.net/really-simple-jquery-scroll-to-function) looks promising, but I don't know how to set it up. There is no demo so I can't see how to set it up. I am not that literate in Javascript. Also, the [ScrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) for jQuery is way too complicated. I am willing to use a plugin that has a lot of options, but I just don't want the options to prevent me from figuring out how to set it up.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the best way I have found to do it - it just uses the normal anchors but extends their functionality

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
    var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-15}, 500);
});
```

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/Z8XDG/)

Comment: What would the HTML markup look like and how would I implement it?

Comment: That's perfect, except I can't seem to replicate the effect on my site using the javascript in the fiddle. I'm sure it's a small error on my part. How do I write in the javascript using onLoad? Do I put it in the header? test site — http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/kate/

Comment: YOu have to include jQuery: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Make sure you add both after your html code. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/Z8XDG/1/

Answer (score 6):

I used straight jquery to do this.

I had a link like so ->

```
<a href="1" class="scrolling">Go to 1</a>
```

then using jquery it would scroll down to a div with another anchor with id "1"

```
$("a.scrolling").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("href"));
});

function goToByScroll(id) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');                               
}
```

Comment: +1 but if you're using jQuery please attach events properly. Using the `onclick` attribute makes my skin crawl.

Comment: I would prefer not to use anchor tags to set the end locations.

Answer (score 2):

There's ScrollTo in Javascript. It's a window event. check it out here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo

Comment: [-1 not enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)         Hehe

Answer (score 0):

I found this code over the internet while searching for a quick way to create this scroll to effect.

html code:

```
<a href="#services">Jump to services</a>
<div id="services"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

});

This is the [Code source](http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery).