# How to redirect the page using jquery

Tags: jquery

My function is when i select the drop down list value,based on that section will goes here.

all id content will be in same page. so i want to go to that section based on selected value

drop down list content

```
    <select class="dropdown" id="select">
    <option id="Choose a Service"">Choose a service</option>
        <option id="physio_content">Physiotheraphy</option>
        <option id="nurse_content">Nursing</option>
        <option id="doctor_content">Doctor</option>
        <option>Training attendant</option>
   </select>
<a href="" class="butt" id="home_btn">Schedule a HOME visit</a>
```

page content

```
<div id="physio_content">
      .........
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("#home_btn").on('click',function(e){

    var lct = $('#select').val();
    document.location.href='#'lct;
 });
```

Comment: so ... you're asking how to have it [scroll the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403513/simple-scroll-to-down-effect-using-minimal-markup-and-hash-tags)?

Comment: its get selected value. but it doesn't goto that section   <a class="butt" id="home_btn">Schedule a HOME visit</a>   it is correct

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Your HTML:
<input type='hidden' id='fieldHidden' />

Your Jquery:
$("#select").on("change", function(){
    $('#fieldHidden').val(this.value);
});
$('#home_btn').click(function(e) {
    var url = $('#fieldHidden').val();
    //alert(url);
    window.location.replace(url);
    //e.preventDefault; 
});
```

Comment: I want to redirect page based on button on anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
$("#home_btn").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var lct = $('#select').children(":selected").attr("id");
    document.location.hash = '#' + lct;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#home_btn").on('click',function(e) {
    var lct = $('#select').val();
    document.location.hash= '#' + lct;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpgLV/2/)</kbd>

Correct your HTML

Id must be unique.So you can use `data-id` attribute on dropdown list

```
<select class="dropdown" id="select">
    <option>Choose a service</option>
    <option data-id="physio_content">Physiotheraphy</option>
    <option data-id="nurse_content">Nursing</option>
    <option data-id="doctor_content">Doctor</option>
    <option>Training attendant</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#home_btn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default behavior of anchor tag 
    var lct = $('#select option:selected').data('id');
    if (lct !== '' && lct !== undefined) { //if data-id is not empty
        document.location.hash = '#' + lct; //jump the location of div
    }
});
```

---

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[event.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Read [two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)